# Async Autocomplete does not show options when label keys are different from filtering keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm not new to ReactJs or Material UI but this one really struck to me as surprise. So I'm using [Material-UI Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) like below. **users** is array of object as shown below. So when I match **firstName** or **lastName** from user table, options are rendered correctly. But if I try to search via email in the table options does not render on focus. Though I'm sure that emails were matched and **users** were return. Now if I change `getOptionLabel={(option) => option.firstName + ' ' + option.lastName }` to `getOptionLabel={(option) => option.email }` it renders via email but search no longer works for `firstName` or `lastName`. So, my question is how can I bypass this behaviour of autocomplete where I can pass any array and autocomplete still show `firstName` and `lastName` keys

**users** array of object

```
[
  {_id: 1, firstName: 'f1abc', lastName: 'l1abc', email: 'user-1@example.com'},
  {_id: 2, firstName: 'f2abc', lastName: 'l2abc', email: 'user-2@example.com'},
  {_id: 3, firstName: 'f3abc', lastName: 'l3abc', email: 'user-3@example.com'},
]

<Autocomplete
    options={users}
    onChange={onChange}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.firstName + ' ' + option.lastName }
    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option._id === value._id}
    value={selectedPatients}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        placeholder='Select Patient'
        onChange={handleChange}
        variant='standard'
      />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show `firstName + lastName` in dropdown but you want to filter on `firstName + lastName + email` you could use Autocomplete's `createFilterOptions` in this way:

```
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
   matchFrom: "any",
   stringify: (option: UserTypeType) => option.firstName + option.lastName + option.email
});

interface UserTypeType {
  _id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
}

...

<Autocomplete
    options={users}
    onChange={onChange}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.firstName + ' ' + option.lastName }
    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option._id === value._id}
    filterOptions={filterOptions}  //<-- here pass filterOptions to Autocomplete
    value={selectedPatients}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        placeholder='Select Patient'
        onChange={handleChange}
        variant='standard'
      />
    )}
/>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-z8m0x?file=/demo.tsx) a working example.